# How do I replace a character with its hex value?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to replace a character with its hex literal. For example before regex:

```
h
```

After regex:

```
0x68
```

I'm trying this:

```
s/\([a-z]\)/\=printf("%#02x", submatch(0))/
```

But this replaces it with

```
00
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that way, `printf` expects a decimal number to be converted to a hexadecimal one. All you need to do is convert the character to a number as follows:

```
s/\([a-z]\)/\=printf("%#02x", char2nr(submatch(0)))/
```

See [`:help char2nr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#char2nr%28%29) for details.